# Jenkins fetch all branches, the build field doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, git-branch

how to prevent Jenkins from fetching all branches in the console it show 
git fetch --tags --progress git@repository-informations +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* 
how to specify fetching a single branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GIT plugin you can specify a branch to build like below:
refs/heads/branchName. If you do not specify a branch all branches will be examined.

[image: Branches option]

Comment: Brnach name as follow: "*/<branch name>"

Comment: even it build a specific branch but Jenkins fetch all branches, Actually I managed to solve this by additional behavious and check shallow clone

Comment: the image is offline